# How do I perform this Partial Fraction Decomp.?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

***Disclaimer: I am not a student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult who is learning Calculus. I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.***

$$\int{\frac{1}{(x^2+2x-4)(x+3)}}dx$$

This led me to $$A=1, B=-1, C=-1$$

However I don't know how to integrate the following:
$$\int{\frac{x-1}{(x^2+2x-4)}}dx$$

Here is my work:
[image]

Comment: You'll need to factor the quadratic and then do partial fractions again

Comment: How do I factor    $x^2+2x-4$  ?  Complete the square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{split}
\int \frac{x-1}{(x^2+2x-4)} dx
 &= \int \frac{x+1}{x^2+2x-4} + \int \frac{-2}{x^2+2x-4} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \ln\left|x^2+2x-4\right| + (-2)\int\frac{dx}{(x+1)^2-5}
\end{split}
$$

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2-5}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}\int(\frac{1}{x+1-\sqrt{5}}-\frac{1}{x+1+\sqrt{5}})dx 
 $$

Comment: +1 very nice, welcome, hope you stay around and contribute more :)

Comment: Is there a simpler way?  The context of this problem implies a less complex method. Also, the solution key provided a very different answer.

Comment: @JackOfAll  I can't find a simpler way